# Running a web server on an Android device with a custom URL?

Tags: java, android, url, networking

I created a simple webserver, which listens on port 8080 on my Android device. I can reach the service by calling 192.168.1.23:8080 in a browser from a laptop which is in the same network.

Question: How can I call the service by an URL?

AirDroid does this, and it works by calling http://web.airdroid.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any domain name can be pointed towards an IP address by setting its DNS settings. If you own a domain name, you can go into the DNS settings and set up a subdomain (eg test.yourdomain.com) with an "A" record with the IP you want (192.168.1.23). Now, assuming you're connected to the internet (so the PC you're accessing from can access DNS servers), if you go to test.yourdomain.com:8080 in a browser on the same network as the phone, it'll request data from 192.168.1.23.

You can do this locally by editing your HOSTS file. If you put an entry into the HOSTS file of a computer ([common file locations are on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)) that looks something like this:

```
192.168.1.23 test.anydomain.com
```

If you then visit http://test.anydomain.com:8080 on the computer with a modified file, it will redirect to your phone. You don't need to own the domain to do this - your HOSTS entry will override whatever the actual domain owner has set up.

If you don't own a domain, you can generally register a subdomain from [noip.com](http://noip.com) or other providers which you can set up with an A record to your local IP address.

Note that none of these options will negate the need for the ":8080" to be appended on the domain. The two ways to get around that are to a. serve web data on port 80 from your phone (it may not be possible?) or b. surround the data the phone's serving in an iFrame. Services like noip may (I've not used it in years) have an option to do a "masked redirect" or something similar, which would essentially just do that.

The airdroid example is not quite the same as this. It seems that they serve (from their servers) a web interface which (I assume) fetches data from your phone in the background.

Comment: Ok, got it. You're right, in the AirDroid use case you are calling a website, which routes information to your device.

Answer (score 0):

first if you use ur webservice on your local pc then you need a server application that can handle this sort of things you can check out IIS if u r using ASP.net and C# or MVC or any microsoft based services .... if u r using PHP there is many software's that can be installed to run php code like WAMP server

second if u r using IIS you will need probably ksoap [link to library](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) which implements webservice based on IIS ... if u r using php then you will need to call it from ur app like this http:// (your ip):(port)/directory name here/yourPHPfile.php